# como eu posso conseguir a permissão publish_actions do facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo no Facebook e preciso da permissão `publish_actions`. Na documentação diz que eu tenho que ter uma aprovação e que é possível testa-la criando um aplicativo de testes para o aplicativo em questão, só que eu não estou conseguindo de nenhum jeito.

Answer (score 1):

Nenhum app pode publicar em nome do usuário sem que você tenha a ação do próprio usuário solicitando isso.

Isso desde 2012 ou 2013 não funciona mais, EXCETO, para aplicativos que comprovem que a ação do usuário não é viável, como por exemplo Smart TVs, que oferecem um atalho para compartilhar o que você está assistindo, mas isso só é viável para DEVICES, aplicativos WEB/DESKTOP devem obrigatoriamente fazer com que o usuário gere tokens de autenticação, que tem validade limitada e restrições do que se pode fazer via API.

Desculpe pela má notícia, é que circulam ainda muitos exemplos de como integrar com os docs antigos!